# Lower openGL version with LWJGL

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

I have an applet , at some computers I get the error :

```
pixel format not accelerated
```

I understand that I get this error if the computer got an older openGL then 4.2 ,now I`m trying

```
PixelFormat pf = new PixelFormat();
        ContextAttribs contex = new ContextAttribs(3,2)
        .withForwardCompatible(true)
        .withProfileCore(true);
```

`Display.create(pf,contex);`

But I recive the following error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.java:2065)
at Tanc.Game.setUpGL(Game.java:1364)
at Tanc.Game$1.run(Game.java:150)
```

clear up

How can I tell LWJGL to use a lower version without error?

Comment: if I use only 
    `ContextAttribs contextAtrributes = new ContextAttribs(4, 2)
       //.withForwardCompatible(true);
       .withProfileCore(true);`
But I get only a black screen so the problem is withForwardCompatible.Any solution?

Comment: Any answer? Still not fund anything....

Comment: Still need help :( can not find anything useful why I receive the error.